# No output from /imu/data

Tags: imu, a200, ubuntu, husky, ubuntu-oneiric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi People,

I am working on Husky A200 Robot from clearpath. I have got an issue with the imu_um6 node of the Robot.

The follwoing is an update of the question with a new form of output that appears simpler to be solved in ros answers:

when I try to run roslaunch imu_um6 test.launch

the following is the output:

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /imu_um6_node/port
- /rosdistro
- /rosversion

NODES

/

imu_pose (imu_um6/imu_pose.py)

imu_tf (tf/static_transform_publisher)

```
imu_um6_node (imu_um6/imu_um6_node.py)

rviz (rviz/rviz)
```

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [imu_um6/imu_um6_node.py]: can't locate node [imu_um6_node.py] in package [imu_um6]

Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored

process[imu_tf-2]: started with pid [7153]

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [imu_um6/imu_pose.py]: can't locate node [imu_pose.py] in package [imu_um6]

Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored

process[rviz-4]: started with pid [7154]

---

After this even my rviz shows up but there is no change in the position or orientation of the imu_link frame whatever motions I create with the hardware...

Any help in debugging this would highly be appreciated.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31709/no-output-from-/imu/data/) by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 612 on 2012-04-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-04-12**:
Can you stop and manually restart the launchfile to see if there are any connection errors? The imu_um6 drivers are not included in ros-electric-imu-drivers - they're installed separately before shipping. You can find the launchfile's location with rospack find.

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-04-16**:
Hi Ryan, can you brief me the commands I need to execute in order to restart the launchfile. I tried finding the package but somehow I could not make it so well... further in one of those packages there was this test.launch file that I tried to launch but there was no change in the overall output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this:

1. Stop the background service with "sudo service clearpath stop"
2. Verify the IMU device name by unplugging it and plugging it back in and running "dmesg"
3. Replace the port name in the test.launch file with the one you found with dmesg
4. Run the node with "roslaunch imu_um6 test.launch" and post your results.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-08-09**:
Eventually I found that the hardware was not working leading to all the confusions. I have ordered a replacement of the product and seems it should be alirght after the new stuff arrives.